# Woocommerce, remove price on product page

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook

I want to move the price and the add2cart button a bit up but somehow can not remove the second price. Not sure if it's about the priority or the theme using it's own price. At least with the theme I did not find anything in their documentation about that.

Here's what I've done:

```
/* CART BUTTON */
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 12);



/* PRICE */
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 30);
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 8);
```

With the cart it worked, but not with the price.

And here is a link to the example: https://staging-lemanja.kinsta.cloud/produkt/paper-light-cape-seide/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below code on css (Hide second price from product detail page)

```
p.price:nth-of-type(2) {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks. but i dont want to remove the price completely. I just want to move it

Comment: you mean you want to remove space of top of the title & remove second price

Comment: i want to remove the second price only

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
span.price
{
    margin-bottom:5px !important;
}
```